Does "can" here sound natural to native English speakers?
I am trying to write a conversation for my military novel, but I am not sure if using "can" here sounds natural to native speakers.
A: The enemy is retreating.
B: No, they are waiting for supplies. Their supply convoy will arrive in two weeks. If they receive any heavy weapons, they can destroy our fortress in January.

can is fine, but heavy weapons would not be considered supplies.

The modal verb can can take Cambridge Dictionary's sense A1:

to be able to

The OP’s sentence is fine and means
If they receive any heavy weapons, they will be able to
destroy our fortress in January.
Also workable is sense A2:

used to express possibility

can
